# Problem trying to join two mysql queries from two different tables in one php function

Tags: php, mysql

the problem it presents is the moment of executing the queries, only I am executing the query of the table example2 and not the query of the table example1.

```
$query  = " SELECT a.id, a.name
                FROM example1 a
                ";
        $query .= " UNION ";
        $query  = " SELECT a.id,a.name
                FROM example2 a
                ";
    $query  .= " WHERE 1 = 1 ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're issue stems from the alias you're applying to the tables:

`FROM example1 a` and `FROM example2 a`

You'll likely want these aliases to be different as they represent different tables, try something like this instead:

```sql
SELECT e1.id, e1.name 
FROM example1 e1 
UNION 
SELECT e2.id, e2.name 
FROM example2 e2 
WHERE 1=1
```

EDIT:

It seems as though the original code was missing a `.=` and was instead just an `=`.

The updated code would be:

```php
$query  = "SELECT e1.id, e1.name FROM example1 e1";
$query .= " UNION ";
$query .= " SELECT e2.id, e2.name FROM example2 e2"; // (.= was missing here)
$query .= " WHERE 1 = 1 ";
```

Comment: the problem I have is that the query of the example1 table and the $query .= " UNION "; are not printing it to me in the query

Comment: Ah, it seems as though you were missing a `.=` on the third assignment. Updated my response.

Comment: I get this error now #1250 - Table 'a' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list. maybe this error is for the alias of tables What must be different as you detailed in ur comment?

Comment: Yes I'd try updating the query to use different aliases for each table as I'd written inititally

Comment: Thanks your comment was helpful